# Display completed Kubernetes ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I've deployed the following ConfigMap with my Kubernetes [DameonSet resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluentd-config
  namespace: fluentd
data:
  source: "#{ENV['MY_SOURCE']}"
```

How can I find out what `source` evaluates to when my DameonSet is deployed?

I've tried the following but it doesn't help:

```
kubectl describe configmaps fluentd-config
```

The output only displays the templated ConfigMap:

```
Name:         fluentd-config
Namespace:    fluentd
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
source: "#{ENV['MY_SOURCE']}"
```

Comment: It will be considered string and remain as is. You may need to use helm or something similar for templating. Check out https://learnk8s.io/templating-yaml-with-code for few solutions.

Comment: @P.... would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: @jakub siemaszko done

Answer (score 1):

By default you cannot do templating of kubernetes yaml manifest files. You would have to use tools like `helm`, there are many more for this.

To illustrate the issue, if you do `kubectl create -f` on the below file, it would not interpolate `$HOME` variable to `/home/ps`, a literal string `$HOME` would be
assigned in`home-dir`.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  home-dir: $HOME
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: my-data-1
```

However, if you would do this imperatively , you can get the variable interpolated.

```
kubectl create  cm my-data-2 --from-literal=home-dir="$HOME" --dry-run=client -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  home-dir: /home/ps
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: my-data-2
```

You can also do variable expansion as below:

```
cat << EOF |kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: v1
data:
  user-name: $USER
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: my-data-3
EOF
```